# Error when compressing jpeg data using

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uiimage, cgimage

I get the following error when trying to compress some jpeg data using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5f);`

```
<Error>: Unsupported pixel description - 4 components, 8 bits-per-component, 32 bits-per-pixel
<Error>: CGBitmapContextCreateWithDictionary: failed to create delegate.
<Error>: CGImageDestinationAddImage image could not be converted to destination format.
<Error>: CGImageDestinationFinalize image destination does not have enough images
```

Here is the code snippet where I download and compress the data...

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:object.largeimage]];
[request startSynchronous];

NSData *imageData = [request responseData];

UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
NSData *compressedImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5f);

//If the data was compressed properly...
if(compressedImageData) [compressedImageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

//If it wasn't...
else [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

[image release];

if(request.responseStatusCode == 200)
object.fullImageFilename = filePath;

[request release];
```

[request release];

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still not sure of the "proper answer", but I managed to find a workaround for anyone who's interested :)

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:object.largeimage]];
[request startSynchronous];

NSData *imageData = [request responseData];

UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
NSData *compressedImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5f);

//If the data was compressed properly...
if(compressedImageData) [compressedImageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];

//If it wasn't...
else
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    compressedImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.5f);
    [compressedImageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];
    [newImage release];
}

[image release];

if(request.responseStatusCode == 200)
    object.fullImageFilename = filePath;

[request release];
```

Comment: This workaround saved me lots of time. Thanks for sharing. In a batch of 20.000 JPEG photo's I have to store in a database, this error occurred on about 250 of them. We still do not know why..